# adding multiple files into TFS server (without doing it for individual files/folders)

Tags: svn, tfs

In SVN folder shell extension, when I right click and select TetroiseSVN->Add option, it give me list of the files that need to be added into SVN. Does TFS has any option for it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. Only top level files are being added. And I have thousands of subfolders, so will not be able to do each individually

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add multiple files and folders recursively in TFS from the source control explorer or the shell extension with [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah i have that installed but don't see it from source control explorer

Comment: I am selecting "Add Items To Folder", then it only list down new files from that folder only. I need a way so all new files in a folder and any sub folders in one step (rather going through each folder manually)

Comment: Are they in the Excluded Items tab?

Comment: actually edit my pervious comment that were a bit misleading.

Comment: It should include all of the subfolders and files on that screen. The destination folder will tell you what folder the file is in.

Comment: there are none for subfolders. Not sure if i am missing something here

Answer (score 0):

Map your workspace to the root of the folders you want to add, you can then drag and drop the folder from explorer in to Source Control Explorer.

Comment: Its already mapped. There are few folders that contain some files that are already added but also have new files that i want to add. So its not that I have to add whole folder, i just need to add new files that are not added into TFS yet

Comment: I think you can still do it by using drag and drop. TFS will only add the files that aren't already checked in. It's worth a shot as the adds will just be pending changes. If it doesn't work how you want then you can just undo pending changes and you be back to where you started